# I want to match two variables on a line and find out how many unique variables there are

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a GraphViz file like this

```
graph {
    edge [arrowhead = none]
    A -> B
    B -> C
    B -> D  [ label="foobar" ];
    C -> A
}
```

and I want to find out, how many nodes there are, e.g. in this case (A, B, C, D) 4.
When I stick with 1-letter nodes, I use a script like this

```
grep -- -\> graph.gv | grep -o . | sort | grep [A-Z] | uniq | wc -l
```

but that fails should I need to use multi-letter nodes.

Ideally I'd have something that just matches

```
match $a -> $b ; echo $a\n $b\n | uniq | wc -l
```

but I have no idea how to do this via sed/grep/awk… whatever works best

Comment: The default output of `dot` produces a new `dot` input file that explicitly declares each node; you should be able to process that output more easily than trying to extract the nodes from edge declarations (especially since multiple edges can be declared in one line with `A -> B -> C`).

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with a hash that skips duplicates:

```
awk '{ arr[$1]++; arr[$3]++ } END { print length(arr) }' infile
```

It yields:

```
4
```

---

**UPDATE**: In [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) there is a pattern section that lets you select a condition to process the line. As I can see in your edit, could be a not-match for curly braces, like:

```
awk '$0 !~ /[{}]/ { arr[$1]++; arr[$3]++ } END { print length(arr) }' infile
```

Comment: I guess this only matches the 1st and 3rd word on each line? That means it also counts the 'header' of the file.

Comment: Yes. Is not what you expect? Are there variable number of nodes?

Comment: Well… there might be other lines with no braces that don't define a node either.

Comment: @user1273684: Well, then your best option is to use an example that covers most of cases. I'm not going to be updating my program while you add more and more different requirements. I think this piece of code is enought to put you in the right direction to a solution.